# Axios POST sends Nonetype data to Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, reactjs, post, django-rest-framework, axios

I am having difficult time trying to figure out the way to post form data through axios to my Django backend, using DRF. Classic Django forms work correct.

Whenever I try to post it using React Modal form, I get a new input in my database, that consists of None's all the way (nulls, I guess?). Serializer doesn't seem to interrupt it and I get a 201 HTTP status. I have no idea where to look for the cause of this problem, I believe I tried almost everything.

I'll post my code so maybe a more experienced eye can catch the root of this error.

components.js/lookup.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:8000`,
  headers: {
    "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
  },
});

function getCookie(name) {
  // gets csrf cookie
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
      // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}

export async function apiLookup(method, endpoint, callback, data) {
  try {
    if (method === "GET") {
      api.get(`${endpoint}`).then((response) => {
        callback(response.data, response.status);
      });
    } else if (method === "POST") {
      axios(
        {
          method: "post",
          url: `http://localhost:8000${endpoint}`,
          data: data,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

employee/lookup.js

```
import { apiLookup } from "../lookup";

export async function apiCreateEmployee(callback, data) {
  let endpoint = "/api/employee/create-employee";
  console.log(data);
  apiLookup("POST", endpoint, callback, data);
}
```

addform.js

```
import React, { createRef } from "react";
import { apiCreateEmployee } from "./lookup";

export function EmployeeCreate(props) {
  const firstNameRef = createRef();
  const lastNameRef = createRef();
  const departmentRef = createRef();
  const positionRef = createRef();
  const salaryRef = createRef();
  const contactNumberRef = createRef();
  const imageRef = createRef();

  const { didAddEmployee } = props;
  const handleBackendUpdate = (response, status) => {
    if (status === 201) {
      didAddEmployee(response);
    } else {
      console.log(response);
      alert("An error occured, please try again");
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newEmployee = {
      first_name: firstNameRef.current.value,
      last_name: lastNameRef.current.value,
      department: departmentRef.current.value,
      position: positionRef.current.value,
      salary: salaryRef.current.value,
      contact_number: contactNumberRef.current.value,
      image: imageRef.current.files[0],
    };
    apiCreateEmployee(handleBackendUpdate, newEmployee);
  };

  const fieldClass = "form-control w-75 p-2 my-2 mx-auto";

  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <form
        className="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column align-content-around mx-auto"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <textarea
          ref={firstNameRef}
          required={true}
          className={fieldClass}
          name="first_name"
          placeholder="First name"
        ></textarea>
        <textarea
          ref={lastNameRef}
          required={true}
          className={fieldClass}
          name="last_name"
          placeholder="Last name"
        ></textarea>
        <textarea
          ref={departmentRef}
          required={true}
          className={fieldClass}
          name="department"
          placeholder="Department"
        ></textarea>
        <textarea
          ref={positionRef}
          required={true}
          className={fieldClass}
          name="position"
          placeholder="Position"
        ></textarea>
        <textarea
          ref={salaryRef}
          required={true}
          className={fieldClass}
          name="salary"
          placeholder="Salary"
        ></textarea>
        <textarea
          ref={contactNumberRef}
          required={true}
          className={fieldClass}
          name="contact_number"
          placeholder="Contact number"
        ></textarea>
        <input
          type="file"
          ref={imageRef}
          required={false}
          className={fieldClass}
          placeholder="Photo"
        ></input>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-3 w-50 mx-auto">
          Add new employee
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

employee/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Employee


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    department = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    position = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    salary = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    contact_number = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    image = serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'department',
                  'position', 'salary', 'contact_number', 'image']

    def get_first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.first_name

    def get_last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.last_name

    def get_department(self, obj):
        return obj.department

    def get_position(self, obj):
        return obj.position

    def get_salary(self, obj):
        return obj.salary

    def get_contact_number(self, obj):
        return obj.contact_number

    def get_image(self, obj):
        print(obj.image)
        return obj.image


class EmployeeCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    department = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    position = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    salary = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    contact_number = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    image = serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'department',
                  'position', 'salary', 'contact_number', 'image']

    def validate_salary(self, value):
        if not value:
            return 0
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('You must supply an integer')

    def validate_contact_number(self, value):
        if not value:
            return 0
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('You must supply an integer')

    def validate_content(self, value):
        if len(value) > settings.MAX_TEXT_LENGTH:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'Maximum text length exceeded.')
        return value

    def get_first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.first_name

    def get_last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.last_name

    def get_department(self, obj):
        return obj.department

    def get_position(self, obj):
        return obj.position

    def get_salary(self, obj):
        return obj.salary

    def get_contact_number(self, obj):
        return obj.contact_number

    def get_image(self, obj):
        print(obj.image)
        return obj.image
```

employee/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class EmployeeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return EmployeeQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def search(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)


class EmployeeQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(first_name__icontains=query) | Q(
                last_name__icontains=query))
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct()
        return qs


class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, max_length=30)
    department = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, max_length=50)
    position = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, max_length=30)
    salary = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=10)
    contact_number = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=10)
    image = models.ImageField(
        default='profile_pic.jpg', upload_to='employee_photos')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

    objects = EmployeeManager()
```

I'll gladly post anything else but I think that the problem might be somewhere in those files.

Thank you so much in advance for any contribution to the solution.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the code snippet below is useless on your code

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'department',
                  'position', 'salary', 'contact_number', 'image']
```

Check your view if you have the multipart parser.

check the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/) for further information

try to log your request.data to check what data really posted on axios.

Comment: My request.data logs what is proper JSON I think:

` {first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", department: "Testing", position: "Tester", salary: "200000", …}
first_name: "John"
last_name: "Doe"
department: "Testing"
position: "Tester"
salary: "200000"
contact_number: "2424282028"
image: undefined
__proto__: Object`

I don't have the Multipart Parser in my view actually, I'll study the docs and try to come up with the solution, if I don't manage on my own, I'll kindly ask for your help again ;) Thanks!

Comment: If you use the serializer above, it can straight away create your data.

e.g.: EmployeeSerializer(data=request.data)

Comment: Wow, you were right, works like a charm! It seems like I tweaked the fields on my serializer for unknown reason :D Only problem now is that it doesn't accept images (I am using AWS S3, it works usind django forms), do you have any idea for a possible solution?

Comment: If you pass it through Formdata instead of json on your axios post
example:
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('first_name', 'me');
formData.append('last_name', 'me2');
...
formData.append("image", image that you uploaded)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Thank you so much for your help again, really means so much to me. I think that with your hints I'll be able to fix that now. Have a great day!